# How to open navigation link in new tab - HTML5

Tags: html

I have created  a navigation menu at my Home Page's header. I've set up the links in the navigation, but I want the links to be opened in a new tab. How can I achieve that?

```
<div class="sticky-nav">
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul id="menu-nav">
            <li class="current"><a href="#home-slider">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Manicures and Pedicures</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hair</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Make Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hair Removal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Skincare</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hamam Maghrabi</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li> 

        </ul>
    </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: if you want to open link in new tab then add _blank to class or style. Like this <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools</a>

Comment: Use target="_blank" in all ur link

Comment: i can try but not working.

Answer (score 4):

More about `a-target` attribute at: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

Use: `<a href="#" target="_blank"`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="sticky-nav">
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul id="menu-nav">
            <li class="current"><a href="#home-slider" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-us.html" target="_blank">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" target="_blank">Contact us</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" target="_blank" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Manicures and Pedicures</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Hair</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Make Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Hair Removal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Skincare</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Hamam Maghrabi</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li> 

        </ul>
    </nav>

</div>
```

Use **target="_blank"** in all your anchor tag

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ggdabbbc/1/)

Comment: U may clear the history and try again. Which browser ur using.

Comment: Try to refresh your page by Ctrl + F5 (or Command + R if you're using Mac), that should clear the cache, though I doubt this will be the issue here. _blank -target should work just perfectly in what you're asking.